# Switching a square-bracket-paired-delimiter command to \DeclaredPairedDelimiter

Tags: compiling, delimiters, mathtools

I'm trying to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` instead of my old roll-your-own commands to the same effect. Well, this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\sparen{\left[}{\right]}
\begin{document}
Hello, world.
$\sparen{123}$.
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
\MT_delim_sparen_nostar_wrapper:nnn ...thopen {#1}
                                                  #2\mathclose {#3}
l.6 $\sparen{123}
                 $.
? X
```

Why?

Comment: Remove the `\left` and `\right`. `\sparen*` will do the resizing.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Make that an answer please.

Comment: @einpoklum:  I have a solution for your previous deleted post (variable sized norm with subscript. Are you interested?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, I deleted it because I wanted time to edit that question so I would have some `\if` condition on the first argument being empty, and then recreate it. But since my `\if`s are rusty that'll take me a bit. Anyway, I'll un-delete it.

Comment: @einpoklum: I have such a solution, based on `xparse`…

Comment: @Bernard: [here it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383195/5640)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `\left` and `\right`. `\sparen*` will do the resizing.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\DeclarePairedDelimiter\sparen{\left[}{\right]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\sparen{[}{]}
\begin{document}
Hello, world.
$\sparen{12\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}3}$
$\sparen*{12\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}3}$.
\end{document}
```